# Can I say, "the article claimed", "the focus of the article is", etc.?

Tags: grammaticality, formality

I once went to a writing centre at a community college and asked if it's more correct to write *the article explains...* or *the author explains...*. The instructor replied that the latter was preferable, as the article *is not saying anything*. Is this right? Can the concept be extended farther?

I just caught my self writing *The focus of the article is...*. Does the same principle apply in that it's the *author's* focus, not actually the *article's* focus?

I'm assuming it doesn't matter if it's an article or other piece of written (or spoken) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding *The article explains...* or *The author explains...*, I would **write**  *the author explains*; if I needed to mention the article, I'd say, "*In the article, the author explains*. In casual speech with friends, however, I think it's fine to say, *the article says*. I certainly do it often enough. Even when discussing scholarly papers, my colleagues do so. It must be common enough in America.

Regarding *The focus of the article is...*, to me this is perfectly acceptable. If we can say, *the book is about...*, we can explain what an article covers/focuses on.

> ... "American doctors and hospitals adopt new technologies even without proof that they work better than older techniques," the *article states*. - medscape.com
>
> Mr. Obama's *speech covered* the range of national security, counterterrorism and civil liberties issues facing the United States since 2001. - The New York Times
>
> The *book tells the story* of a young farm boy named Eragon, who finds a mysterious stone in the mountains. - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragon‎

Comment: +1, and I'd like to note that sites such as Wikipedia may be beginning to change this usage since there is often any number of (potentially anonymous) authors. It is appropriate to refer to an article's *explanation* so it seems appropriate to refer to it as *explaining* something. "This article explains how to chop wood."